# Redis - How to get the distinct between two list

Tags: redis

I have two different key (KeyA and KeyB) that their contains a list of numbers. I would like to match the list in KeyA with KeyB and get just the distinct number from list in KeyA. Is it possible? Thanks in advance.

Comment: maybe interesting? http://redis.io/commands/sinter

Comment: Thanks Ryan. It helped me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no native command that intersects Redis Lists. You could do that in a server-side Lua script, but the performance would be so so because Lists do not provide constant lookup time for anything but their ends.

A better way would be to keep a Set for each List, with the elements of the List added to the Set. Then you can use all Set operations on the Sets, specifically [`SINTER`](http://redis.io/commands/sinter) in your case.

Comment: Thank so much. I will try it I will let you know. I think [`SINTERSTORE`](http://redis.io/commands/sinterstore) could be perfect for what I want to do.

Comment: It worked!. In my case the function that I have to use is: [SDIFF](http://redis.io/commands/sdiff) and [SDIFFSTORE](http://redis.io/commands/sdiffstore) because I was looking for the distinct between 2 set not the intersection. Thank so much for your help.